# Python - Combine plots in grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a function (see end) that calculates spherical harmonic coefficients for a specific order and degree and plots them on a sphere.

I would like to combine several of these spheres in a grid.  I would like an end result similar to this[image]

I tried with 2 plots using plt.subplots and plt.gridSpec to no avail. It always ends up putting the other plot outside. Here's the code I tried:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2)
ax1, ax2 = axes.ravel()
ax1.plot(sh(6,6))
ax2.plot(sh(7,7))
plt.show()
```

I get the following figure:

[image]

and a traceback @ 3rd line:

> ValueError: x and y must not be None

Also,

```
### GridSpec ####
plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,0))
sh(7,7)
plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 0))
sh(8,7)
plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 1))
sh(9,7)
plt.show()
```

results in 3 separate (not grid) plots.

It is a better result but the 3rd sphere should be on the right of the 2nd sphere unless I have done something wrong.
Note: sh() is the function I wrote which calculates the spherical harmonics **and** plots the sphere with the spherical harmonics projections. In other words I have 2 spheres here. All I want to do is combine the two (actually more) spheres in a grid like the one above.

PS: I tried to work with Mayavi but I couldn't make it work. All the code on the website doesn't work for me. I will recheck it later but I am tight on time now so I wrote my own function.

The function I wrote:

```
def sh(l,m,cent_lat,cent_lon):
    # function that calculates the spherical harmonics of order l and degree m and visualizes it on a
    # sphere centered at (cent_lat, cent_lon) given in degrees

    if l < m:
        print "Order cannot be smaller than the degree! Try again."
    else:

        import numpy as np
        import scipy.special as sp
        from math import pi
        import matplotlib.cm as cm
        from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        res = pi/100 # resolution
        theta = np.r_[0:2*pi:res]; phi = np.r_[0:pi:res] # theta: lon, phi: coalt

        coef = []
        for i in theta:
            for j in phi:
                coef.append(sp.sph_harm(m,l,i,j))
        coef = np.asarray(coef) # convert list to array
        coef = np.reshape(coef, (len(theta),-1)) # reshapte array as per number of angles


        ## Plotting ##

        # create lat/lon arrays
        lon = np.linspace(0,2*pi,len(theta))
        lat = np.linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,len(phi))
        colat = lat+pi/2 # colatitude array

        # create 2D meshgrid
        mesh_grid = np.meshgrid(lon, lat) # create a meshgrid out of lat/lon
        lon_grid = mesh_grid[0] # grab the meshgrid part for lon
        lat_grid = mesh_grid[1] # grab the meshgrid part for lat

        real_coef = np.real(coef) # read parts of the coefficients
        norm_coef = np.round(real_coef / np.max(real_coef),2) # normalize

        # set up orthographic map projection
        mp = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0 = cent_lat, lon_0 = cent_lon) # setup an orthographic basemap centered at lat_0 & lon_0
        # draw the edge of the map projection region (the projection limb)
        mp.drawmapboundary()

        # convert angles from radians to degrees & pipe them to basemap
        x,y = mp(np.degrees(lon_grid), np.degrees(lat_grid)) 

        cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # Set color map
        mp.pcolor(x,y,np.transpose(norm_coef), cmap=cmap)
        # cax = figure.add_axes([0.15,0.03,0.7,0.03])
#         cb = plt.colorbar(orientation = 'horizontal')
        plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I tried with 2 plots using plt.subplots and plt.gridSpec to no avail", show your code and the result. I was going to tell you to use that exactly.

Comment: Or use `mayavi`, they have an example which is similar http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_spherical_harmonics.html

Comment: @tglaria: I updated my question & added the code.

Comment: @EdSmith: My function already does what Mayavi's does. What I need is to combine several spheres  in a grid.

Comment: Have you tried turning it around, and passing `ax1/ax2` to `sh` to make it use the existing axes for plotting?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Could you be a bit more explicit please? I am a novice.

Comment: I meant changing the definition of `sh`, so that you can call it with `sh(ax1,6,6)`, and *inside* `sh` you can call a necessary plot command as `ax.plot_surf` (or something similar) using the input `ax` handle of the axes to use. So you create the axes with `subplots`, just as you did, and then *pass those axes to the spherical harmonic plotting function*. It's just not clear to me that what you're currently doing is equivalent to what I'm saying:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I updated the post with more details. The idea is that my function has its own meshgrid and axis to be able to plot the spherical harmonics on the sphere.
What I want to achieve is have another function that calls sh() and plots as many spheres are requested by the user (dependent on the 1st argument of sh(), which is the order of the spherical harmonics)

Comment: Without showing us what `sh()` does (plotting-wise), it will be hard to say anything definite. You probably *shouldn't* put `sh()` into `ax1.plot()`. What does `sh()` even return? I would do this: write `sh()` such that it plots a *single* spherical harmonic with a given `l,m`, and generate the necessary amount of axes *outside* `sh()`. Then each axes can be passed to each `sh()`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I added the function. It returns a plot.

Comment: I don't think your function returns anything.

Comment: It does produce a plot when called like: sh(10,7,30,100)

Comment: I think you're messing around too much with the plots. Try to simplify your code first and THEN put it all in your function (I'd use a class though and use at least two functions: one for calculations and another for plotting). About your function, it's not returning anything, it is plotting, yes, but where? How can you be certain the the figure that's beeing plotted inside the function is the same than the one outside?

Comment: Why don't you use one function for calculations, return its data and plot outside that function?

Answer (score 3):

[`GridSpec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) works for me (`matplotlib` v1.5.0 in case it matters):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
import matplotlib.cm as cm

import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

import numpy as np


u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

ls = LightSource(270, 45)
rgb = ls.shade(z, cmap=cm.gist_earth, vert_exag=0.1, blend_mode='soft')


def plot_sphere(s):

    s.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, facecolors=rgb,
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)

    s.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
    s.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
    s.w_zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

    s.w_xaxis.line.set_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
    s.w_yaxis.line.set_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
    s.w_zaxis.line.set_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

    s.set_xticks([])
    s.set_yticks([])
    s.set_zticks([])


fig = plt.figure()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(6, 7)

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        if i >= j:
            s = fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j+1], projection='3d')
            plot_sphere(s)


for i in range(6):

    pos = gs[i,0].get_position(fig)
    fig.text(pos.x0, (pos.y0 + pos.y1) / 2, "$\\ell = " + str(i) + "$", fontsize=16)

fig.savefig('t.png')
```

[image]